# Building RPM from source, how to install packages required to build in spec file

Tags: linux, centos, package, rpm, rpm-spec

I'm new to building `RPM` packages and writing `spec` file for that.
I have to write a spec file for building a package from `github` source code written in `golang`.
Instead of installing golang, I'm trying to download tar and extract and use that because installation of that is not allowed in production system.
Everything is working fine except the part that when I try to build the code using `bin/go build` it fails with a system header file : `fatal error: systemd/sd-journal.h: No such file or directory`.
This works well when I install the `system-devel` package on that system.
But how do I install it by mentioning in spec file rather than manually.
When I specify it in the `BuildRequires` or `Requires` section, it fails in the starting.
I can not `yum install` because that needs sudo access and rpm is being build with non-sudo access.
How else can I install it , any suggestion is appreciable .

Thanks

Comment: As noted in answers, you need those things installed. If you don't have root on the machine, then consider [building the RPM within a container](http://saule1508.github.io/build-rpm-with-docker/) or a VM.

Comment: You may find this useful https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Golang/

Comment: @msuchy: Thanks for responding, it helped . I used mostly concepts from this page. But I think installing dependencies before building are independent of golang concept so I was looking for an to install those packages which are required for a golang package to work.

Answer (score 2):

Building RPM works in 2 different phases here:

1. All the dependencies are installed.
2. The RPM is compiled

The second phase is the actual `rpmbuild` command. It can only use `Require` or `BuildRequire` for dependencies. As you noticed, it runs as a normal user, so it can not install the dependencies. It can only check for them and abort. This is normal (and expected).

The first phase is actually run by the build servers (eg, Fedora's `koji`), or manually, but it's outside the scope of `rpmbuild`. It's perfectly fine if you manually have to `sudo yum install systemd-devel` before `rpmbuild` will work. But build servers actually automate it using the `yum-builddep` (or `dnf build-dep`) commands. These commands take a spec file and install all of their listed dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @omajid for explaining that. 
Is there a way the build servers can detect and download such dependency , in my case the build would be run by the team city agents so thinking of adding some mechanism to install these packages

Comment: `yum-builddep /path/to/file.spec -y` should install dependencies using `yum`. Needs sudo, just like all other `yum` commands.